# Cluster plot does not work when unique values in the test data are less than 5

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis

I provided the full code that I am having trouble with at the bottom-most part of this post. I am specifically having trouble with this part of the code:

```
    hex_colors = []
    for _ in np.unique(labels):
        hex_colors.append('#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))

    colors = [hex_colors[int(i)] for i in labels]
```

The problem is, when the unique numbers in "labels" are less than 5, the code gives me an "IndexError: list index out of range" however when the unique values in labels are 5 and above, it works just fine. I've been checking what the problem is but couldn't figure it out. Can anyone enlighten me what is causing this error? Thank you very much.

The full code is here:

```
def plot_clustering(z_run, labels, engine ='matplotlib', download = False, folder_name ='clustering'):


    def plot_clustering_matplotlib(z_run, labels, download, folder_name):

    labels = labels[:z_run.shape[0]] # because of weird batch_size

    hex_colors = []
    for _ in np.unique(labels):
        hex_colors.append('#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))

    colors = [hex_colors[int(i)] for i in labels]

    z_run_pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components=3).fit_transform(z_run)
    z_run_tsne = TSNE(perplexity=80, min_grad_norm=1E-12, n_iter=3000).fit_transform(z_run)

    plt.scatter(z_run_pca[:, 0], z_run_pca[:, 1], c=colors, marker='*', linewidths=0)
    plt.title('PCA on z_run')
    if download:
        if os.path.exists(folder_name):
            pass
        else:
            os.mkdir(folder_name)
        plt.savefig(folder_name + "/pca.png")
    else:
        plt.show()

    plt.scatter(z_run_tsne[:, 0], z_run_tsne[:, 1], c=colors, marker='*', linewidths=0)
    plt.title('tSNE on z_run')
    if download:
        if os.path.exists(folder_name):
            pass
        else:
            os.mkdir(folder_name)
        plt.savefig(folder_name + "/tsne.png")
    else:
        plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the list `labels` is unclear but it seems to contain strings of numbers. I suggest using a dictionary to avoid dealing with index numbers back and forth:

```
import numpy as np

labels = ["0", "3", "A", "1", "3", "B", "7", "A", "34"]

hex_colors = {label: '#%06X' % np.random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF) for label in np.unique(labels)}

colors = [hex_colors[label] for label in labels]
print(colors)
```